# cloud sql not showing correct data in table

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql

I imported my csv file in Cloud SQL, and my output is the following:

```
mysql> create table cmc4 (alt_name varchar(40), price int(20), market_cap int(20), circulating_supply int(20), volume int(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
mysql> SELECT * FROM cmc4;
+------------------------------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+--------+
| alt_name                                 | price | market_cap | circulating_supply | volume |
+------------------------------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+--------+
| "0,Bitcoin,"26,788.19","497,813,805,585" |  NULL |       NULL |               NULL |   NULL |
+------------------------------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

The csv file has 100 rows and 5 columns

```
"0,Bitcoin,""26,788.19"",""497,813,805,585"",""18,583,331"",""2,326,819"""
"1,Ethereum,725.67,""83,061,957,583"",""114,016,892"",""45,376,555"""
"2,Tether,0.999656,""20,781,215,588"",""20,820,866,934"",""97,539,460,417"""
"3,XRP,0.295591,""13,428,490,234"",""45,404,028,640"",""31,737,625,738"""
"4,Litecoin,133.90,""8,903,388,270"",""66,187,462"",""102,857,902"""
"5,Bitcoin Cash,368.00,""6,856,086,460"",""18,600,863"",""20,521,085"""
"6,Cardano,0.166834,""5,226,121,155"",""31,112,484,646"",""10,904,863,300"""
```

My problem is that it only shows 1 row, and everything is in the first column of the table that I created in Cloud sql.

Comment: *The csv file has ... 5 columns* I cannot find how these columns values are delimited and/or quoted.

Comment: If you want to tell that leading/trailing `"` are excess and all another are doubled, and the values are separated with commas and enclosed with dquotes, then simply count the amount of values in row 2... I see 6 values in each row except 1st one.

Comment: ?There are 6 values in each row yes including the first row. The index name, coin name, price, market cap, circulating supply and volume are the different columns.

Comment: Can you add how do you imported this csv?